Differential-mode gain for mismatched \$g_m\$ in differential amplifiers
[Source of figures and equations are Design of Analog CMOS Integrated Circuits by Razavi]
I am struggling to figure out how to derive this red-border expression of differential mode gain. He states to look from the Fig 4.17 to derive this expression.The denominator of the differential gain appears to be related to the equation for \$V_p\$ in Fig 4.34, but the connection is not well understood either. How do I come up with this differential mode expression?
This question is related to differential gain for mismatched \$g_m\$ in differential amplifiers




$$
\Delta V_{\text{out1}} = g_{m1} (\Delta V_{\text{in}} - V_p) \left\{ \frac{R_D}{\frac{1}{g_{m2}} + R_{\text{ss}}} \right\}
$$
$$
\Delta V_{\text{out2}} = g_{m2} (-\Delta V_{\text{in}} - V_p) \left\{ \frac{R_D}{\frac{1}{g_{m1}} + R_{\text{ss}}} \right\}
$$
$$
\frac{\Delta V_{\text{out1}} - \Delta V_{\text{out2}}}{\Delta V_{\text{in}}}
$$
\$A_{DM}\$ is required by the above

I arrived at the answer on my own and leave it as a reminder.




I expect the substitution of formulae resolves to (4.56) {CM-(CM-DM)=DM}
$$ | (4.37) - (4.53) |  = (4.56)  $$


Thanks for the comment. However, I am still not convinced.
It seems that $A_{DM}$ is a differential mode gain and has nothing to do with common-mode gain ($A_{CM}$) or gain caused by errors in common-mode signals($A_{CM-DM}$).

I have solved this problem on my own. I'm sorry, but it turns out none of your answers were on point and made any sense.

$A_{DM}$ and $A_{CM}$  do share parameters in common. I used the book's logic.

However, the above equation(|(4.37)−(4.53)|=(4.56)) does not seem to hold true when calculated. I apologize for asking this while I’m the one seeking answers, but can you say with confidence that it’s correct?

Indeed, you can understand that the parameters are shared by reading the book, but you are probably misunderstanding the definition of Acm-dm.

It is clearly stated that $A_{CM-DM}$ as the denom. of CMRR as the unwanted signal gain defined as the difference in gains for CM-DM. But CMRR is also $CMRR=ΔVcm / ΔVout$

”It is clearly stated that $A_{CM−DM}$
as the denom. of CMRR as the unwanted signal gain defined as the difference in gains for CM-DM. ” I coul'nt find the statement.

The input of $A_{CM−DM}$ and $A_{CM}$ is $V_{in,cm}$. However the input of $A_{DM}$
is not $V_{in,cm}$ but $V_{in, dm}$ . That's why |(4.37)−(4.53)|=(4.56) doesn't work.

My reference to the quote is the last line before (4.55)

4.55 only shows the definition of CMRR, not the definition of $A_{CM-DM}$.  As I have said multiple times, you do not understand the definition of $A_{CM-DM}$.         $A_{CM-DM} ≠ A_{CM} - A_{DM}$

I was wrong (4.55)   A{cm-dm}  is the conversion gain from a CM to a DM mismatches (Vx-Vy)/Vcm and not (Acm - Adm)

Absolutely! Thank you for the discussion!
